# Passing variables in django browser string

Tags: python, django

I am doing a search on the page with the ability to filter. It is necessary to pass the selected fields to form the correct `queryset`. What is the best way to do this? I am creating str variable in `urls`. But what if you need to pass 10 or more filter conditions? how to organize dynamically passed variables?

**urls**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('', OrdersHomeView.as_view(), name='orders_home'),
    path('filter/<str:tag>', OrdersFilterView.as_view(), name='orders_filter'),
]
```

I understand what to do through `?var=&var2=`, as in php, but I can't figure out how? it is possible to just process the string `str`, but maybe there is some django magic?

Comment: what about using a search form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the filter view to work with URL GET params:

```
page = request.GET.get('page', 0)
page_size = request.GET.get('page_size', 100)
```

Then construct your URLs to send the filters `filter/tag/?page=1&page_size=20`